# C - Different array behavior linux/windows?

Tags: c, linux

I have a litle probem with C programming. I have to write a programm for the university and I wrote the whole programm on my windows pc. 
I tried it afterwards on a linux system and I got different output.

Here is the code:

```
char *compress(char *input,int lineSize)    
{   
    int n = 0;
    char *compr = (char*)malloc(lineSize * sizeof(char));
    //compr++;

    char c = *input;    

    while(*input != '\0')
    {
        printf("compr: %s\n",compr);
        if(*input != c)
        {
             snprintf(compr,lineSize,"%s%c%d",compr,c,n);

             n = 0;
             c = *input;
             n++;    
        }
        else
        {

            n++;
        }

        input++;

    }

    snprintf(compr,lineSize,"%s%c%d%c",compr,c,n,'\0');
    printf("compr: %s\n",compr);          

    return compr;    
}
```

this works as it should on my windows pc, but when I run it on linux I get a file writing error + the "compr" array is empty :/

I hope anyone could help me, couldnt find any solution.
thanks

Comment: this might be irrelevant, but what compilers are you using?

Comment: Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And install Linux on your own laptop.

Comment: -edit: I used char *compr = (char*)malloc(lineSize * sizeof(char)) ...posted wrong code...but even with this corrected its not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile with warnings:

```
warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

Another possible problem:

```
snprintf(compr,lineSize,"%s%c%d%c",compr,c,n,'\0');
```

From the `sprintf` man page:

> Some programs imprudently rely on code such as the following
>
> sprintf(buf, "%s some further text", buf);
>
> to append text to buf. However, the standards explicitly note that the
>   results are undefined if source and destination buffers overlap when
>   calling sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), and vsnprintf(). Depending
>   on the version of gcc(1) used, and the compiler options employed,
>   calls such as the above will not produce the expected results.

Comment: -edit: I used char compr = (char)malloc(lineSize * sizeof(char)) ...posted wrong code...but even with this corrected its not working...

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution but do you know a other way, not using snprintf?

Comment: `snprintf` its ok, but use two different buffers: `snprintf(res,lineSize,"%s%c%d%c",compr,c,n,'\0');`, of course you need to reserve space (using `malloc`) for `res`

Comment: @Dave, reduce your code to a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example) and edit your question in order to get more help.